# Selecting Values from One Multi Index Dataframe to Add to a New Column in Another Existing Multi Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, multi-index

Alright I could use a little help on this one. I've created a function that I can feed two multi index dataframes into, as well as a list of kwargs, and the function will then take values from one dataframe and add them to the other into a new column.

Just to try to make sure that I'm explaining it well enough, the two dataframes are both stock info, where one dataframe is my "universe" or stocks that I'm analyzing, and the other is a dataframe of market and sector ETFs.

So what my function does is takes kwargs in the form of:

```
new_stock_column_name = "existing_sector_column_name"
```

Here is my actual function:

```
def map_columns(hist_multi_to, hist_multi_from, **kwargs):
    ''' Map columns from the sector multi index dataframe to a new column
        in the existing universe multi index dataframe.

        **kwargs should be in the format newcolumn="existing_sector_column"
    '''
    df_to = hist_multi_to.copy()
    df_from = hist_multi_from.copy()

    for key, value in kwargs.items(): 
        df_to[key] = np.nan

        for index, val in df_to.iterrows():
            try:
                df_to.loc[index, key] = df_from.loc[(index[0],val.xl_sect),value]
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return df_to
```

I believe my function works exactly as I intend, except it takes a ridiculously long time to loop through the data. There has got to be a better way to do this, so any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

I apologize in advance, but I'm having trouble coming up with two simple example dataframes, but the only real requirement is that the stock dataframe has a column that lists its sector ETF in it, and that column value directly coincides to the level 1 index of the ETF dataframe.

The exception handler is in place simply because the ETFs sometimes do not exist for all the dates of the analysis, in which case I don't mind that the values stay as NaN.

Update:
Here is a revised code snippet that will allow you to run the function to see what I'm talking about. Forgive me, my coding skills are limited.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

stock_arrays = [np.array(['1/1/2020','1/1/2020','1/2/2020','1/2/2020']),
                np.array(['aapl', 'amzn', 'aapl', 'amzn'])]
stock_tuples = list(zip(*stock_arrays))
stock_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(stock_tuples, names=['date', 'stock'])

etf_arrays = [np.array(['1/1/2020','1/1/2020','1/2/2020','1/2/2020']),
                np.array(['xly', 'xlk','xly', 'xlk'])]
etf_tuples = list(zip(*etf_arrays))
etf_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(etf_tuples, names=['date', 'stock'])

stock_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4), index=stock_index, columns=['close_price'])
etf_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4), index=etf_index, columns=['close_price'])

stock_df['xl_sect'] = np.array(['xlk', 'xly','xlk', 'xly'])

def map_columns(hist_multi_to, hist_multi_from, **kwargs):
    ''' Map columns from the sector multi index dataframe to a new column
        in the existing universe multi index dataframe.

        **kwargs should be in the format newcolumn="existing_sector_column"
    '''
    df_to = hist_multi_to.copy()
    df_from = hist_multi_from.copy()

    for key, value in kwargs.items(): 
        df_to[key] = np.nan

        for index, val in df_to.iterrows():
            try:
                df_to.loc[index, key] = df_from.loc[(index[0],val.xl_sect),value]
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return df_to
```

Now after running the above in a cell, you can access the function by calling it like this:

```
new_stock_df = map_columns(stock_df, etf_df, sect_etf_close='close_price')
new_stock_df
```

I hope this is more helpful. And as you can see, the function works, but with really large datasets it's extremely slow and inefficient.

Comment: Looks like you want a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). Do those examples help? It's hard to figure out what you want without a few sample dataframes (2 or 3 rows and 2 or 3 columns would do...)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not certain if that's what I'm trying to do. The column that I would want to "join" on will have multiple entries on a single date that correspond to the index of the 2nd dataframe. 

I have now created a couple of example dataframes.